# Repeated tasks are not jumping correctly to next date

Tags: org-agenda

I have been noticing that my repeated tasks are all over the place. I started noticing that they were not showing up in my agenda... so I went to the agenda orgmode file where they are programmed.

As you see below, eg., this task has jumped from the 17th of November to the 17th of February... when it should jump to the 17th of December.

[image]

Any help welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure how you did the state transitions, but if you repeatedly change state to `DONE`, even if you do that on a single day, the repeat date will advance by a month *each time*. I suspect that is what happened here, but there is not enough information to be sure. In any case, I tried with a simple file and I certainly cannot get directly from today's date to next February: I can only do that by doing the state transition repeatedly or by changing the date manually. If you can give more information on what exactly you are doing, please add it to the question itself, not in a comment.

Comment: I do t-d from the Agenda view. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Well, it should *not* happen and AFAICS it does not happen. You must have *something* in your configuration that causes this. You could bisect your init file but if you can't detect immediately that there is a problem, that makes the debugging much harder.  You might want to go back to as minimal a configuration of Org mode as you can manage and make sure that the problem does not arise and then bring in additional capabilities *one at a time*, while continuing to check for the problem. Depending on how extensive your configuration is, you might want to add your init file to the question...

Comment: ... just in case somebody can spot something suspicious.